# How to move object outside Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to place the zoomControl and panControl outside Google Map. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Someone who have idea please share it. Thanks :)

Comment: I doubt this is possible but I'd love to be proved wrong. You could improve this question a lot by showing your existing map code and demonstrating what you've already tried.

Comment: your question is not complete please elaborate it so that we can help you dear.

Comment: I want to place the zoomControl and panControl outside Google Map. using div tag or any other tactics that might help me about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manipulate the default map controls like this.

Sure, you may be able to find a way to hack it. But your hack will break when Google updates their map objects.

Instead, if you want controls outside the map, *remove* the standard controls entirely, and then create your own controls outside the map and connect them up with the Maps API.

To remove the pan and zoom controls, you'd use this in your options when you create the map:

```
var mapOptions = {
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    // your other options here
};
```

Then use ordinary HTML elements such as buttons to implement your own controls on your page. When those elements are clicked, call [`map` methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) such as `panBy()` or `setZoom()` to implement their actions.

This way you can provide your own controls outside the map with assurance that they will continue to work when the Maps API is revised.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that is to create your own design of zoom and panel. Because the zoomControl and panControl are contained to Google Map

Answer (score -3):

Yup, that's possible. Put your margin css on the element you wanna move and change overflow:hidden to overflow:visible on all frame divs via js.